# i trying to assign value of dynamic check box to dropdown list but its shows same value because is of check box is same

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

it only pick first value from dynamic checkbox, when i click on check box i want to assign dynamic checkbox value in dropdown list

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            //var val = $("#country option:selected").val();
            var val = $("#c1").val();
            $("#country").val(val);
            alert(val);
        } else if ($(this).is(":not(:checked)")) {
            alert("Checkbox is unchecked.");
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<select name="cat_id1" id="country" onChange="ajaxFunction()">
    <option value=0>Show All</option>
    <?php
        foreach ($results as $result) { 
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $result[mem_ID];?>"><?php echo $result[mem_email];?></option>
    <?php
        }
    ?>
</select>
<td>
    <input type="checkbox" name="name[]" id="c1" value="<?php echo $result['mem_email']; ?>">
</td>
```

Comment: Please review your code. I tried it, and it works. Let's check the console. do you get any error, double check is the options has the value as checkbox.

Comment: Check this, it works: https://jsfiddle.net/6gymee4a/

Comment: thanks for ur responce yes options has the value as checkbox. but check box has generated dynamicallyvar val = $("#c1").val(); c1 is fixed , it always pick first value

Comment: since c1 is fixed thats why it picks first record from list..how to pass c1 dynimically to js.....var val = $("#c1").val();// all chek box hold same id ie c1....how assign value from chekbox which we select..

Comment: http://prntscr.com/b8mlyk

Comment: http://prntscr.com/b8mm6m

Comment: Do you have a live example?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/6gymee4a/7/

Comment: $("#country").val($("#c1").val());// here c1 is fixed in js ..how to change it to pick the selected checkbox value...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after I've checked the code presented by OP:

`id` attribute should always be unique on the page. You can not add `id="c1"` for 3 chekboxes, only for one.

Instead of using `id` use a class selector.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="name[]" id="someUniqeu" class="selectTrigger" value="<?php echo $result['mem_email']; ?>">
```

Then use it in your jQuery:

```
$('.selectTrigger').click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
       ("#country").val($(this).val());
```